# "CommandBus" with Handlers & Observers

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm looking for a very simple (at first sight) `CommandBus`, which will handle some `ICommand` publication. The `CommandBus` implementation will find the appropriate `IHandler` to `Execute` the Command and then `Notify` some possible `IObservers`.

My first step is to make it work, I've chosen to use a synchronous dependency injection pattern which I may extends in the future, maybe using a real `ServiceBus` with some asynchronous capability.

Here is the abstract definition:

```
public interface ICommandBus
{
    TResult Publish<TCommand, TResult>(TCommand command)
        where TResult : ICommandResult
        where TCommand : ICommand<TResult>;
}

public interface ICommand<T>
    where T : ICommandResult
{
    int Id_User { get; }
}

public interface ICommandResult
{
    bool Success { get; }

    Exception Error { get; }

    ICollection<ValidationRule> BrokenRules { get; }
}

public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>
    where TCommand : ICommand<TResult>
    where TResult : ICommandResult
{
    TResult Execute(TCommand command);
}

public interface ICommandObserver<TCommand, TResult>
    where TCommand : ICommand<TResult>
    where TResult : ICommandResult
{
    void Trigger(TCommand command, TResult result);
}
```

And here is the `CommandBus` implementation (using `Structuremap` as the DI)

```
public class CommandBus : ICommandBus
{
    private readonly IContainer m_container;

    public CommandBus(IContainer container)
    {
        m_container = container;
    }

    public TResult Publish<TCommand, TResult>(TCommand command)
        where TResult : ICommandResult
        where TCommand : ICommand<TResult>
    {
        using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("CommandBus.Publish"))
        {
            var handler = m_container.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>>();
            var observers = m_container.GetAllInstances<ICommandObserver<TCommand, TResult>>();

            var result = handler.Execute(command);

            foreach (var observer in observers)
                observer.Trigger(command, result);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
public class CreateItemCommand: ICommand<CreateItemResult>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
public class CreateItemResult: ICommandResult
{
    public bool Success { get; private set; }
}

var command = new CreateItemCommand();
var result = commandBus.Publish<CreateItemCommand, CreateItemResult>(command);
```

What do you think about this pattern? Do you think it will be easy to upgrade? I'm afraid it can be an obvious bottleneck in my application...

**Edit:** I just want to past a [link to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442141/generic-interface-of-generic-interface-with-generics) about this pattern, in order to simplify all the Generics...

Comment: Is it or is it not working as intended?

Comment: Everyhing is working well, and I'm satisfied with performance. But I would like to make it easiser to use (see my bonus question :)). And mostly, I would like to know if it looks easy to upgrade or not, because this pattern is new for me...

Comment: I've removed the "bonus question" as it's off-topic for this site (code here must be working in order to have it reviewed).  If you'd like help on that part, post this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Jamal My bad, I will do as you said :)

Comment: You may want to include a snippet showing how it's being used in an application.

Comment: "How to use" added

Answer (score 2):

This is *insanely nit-picky*, but this is really just driving me nuts.

> ```
> TResult Publish<TCommand, TResult>(TCommand command)
> ```

We read left to right from the return type to the name to the parameters, but you're ordered your generic types from param to result. I think this would be much easier to read as

```
TResult Publish<TResult, TCommand>(TCommand command)
```

It keeps the declaration closer to its use. Which is, admittedly, trivial in this case, but I think it makes the signature read more like a sentence.

On another note though, I *really* like that you're filtering the acceptable types. It reminds me that I need to do this more often myself. It's better than just trusting that you (or someone else most likely) knows what kind of types are okay to use generically.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the your problem is you are deviating from the meaning of the **Command** and **Bus**.

### re Command

A telltale sign of this is where you have type parameters on the type declaration which are not used in the signatures of the methods. Such as:

```
public interface ICommand<T>
    where T : ICommandResult
{ }
```

and

```
public class CreateItemCommand: ICommand<CreateItemResult>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Above is a perverse dependency from a value object to its users. The raison d'etre of commands is to break such dependencies.

### re Bus

Bus is a communication channel. You send messages through a channel. A bus doesn't return anything. It can or cannot send a message. If it can't, it is an exception by definition. A command bus can be async, your `ICommandBus` cannot.

It may be the case that your application will never need async, load balancing, etc. The you don't need a Bus. A bus stands between the publisher and the handler. A return type, runtime errors, concurrency exceptions etc are concerns of the handler.

This is a type-cast through the backdoor. Instead of :

```
var result = commandBus.Publish<CreateItemCommand, CreateItemResult>(command);
```

You can do just:

```
var result = commandHandler.handle(command);
```

Note a handler can handle many types of command.

```
class CommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateItemCommand, CreateItemResult>,  
    ICommandHandler<PokeItemCommand, PokeItemResut>, ...
```

### Validation and CommandBus

A client is responsible for validating commands before posting it to a command bus. Because, simply put, a bus shouldn't return a result. See a better explanation and much more insight (by Udi Dahan) [here](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/).

One relevant piece is

> In thinking through what could make a command fail, one topic that
>   comes up is validation. Validation is different from business rules in
>   that it states a context-independent fact about a command. Either a
>   command is valid, or it isn’t. Business rules on the other hand are
>   context dependent.

I strongly recommend you read the whole article.

Whereas in

```
public interface ICommandResult
{
    bool Success { get; }

    Exception Error { get; }

    ICollection<ValidationRule> BrokenRules { get; }
}
```

There maybe some broken rules while the result is successful. This indicates `BrokenRules` and `Success` should probably not be on the same type.

The same is true for `Error` and `Success`, also. `Success == true && Error != null`.

Normally you validate a command before you try to handle it.

And validation would always be synchronous, whereas one would like to have the option to handle some commands asynchronous. If you would handle a command synchronously then you wouldn't put a bus between the handler and the client.

### Solution

There seems to be a duplication in `ICommandObserver`/`ICommandHandler`. Also `ICommandObserver`,`ICommandHandler` and `ICommandResult` altogether seems to be duplicating [`IObserver<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And this library is missing [`IObservable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782981%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so `ICommandBus` is strangely not async.

`ICommand` is just a marker interface. You could drop it altogether if you wanted to:

```
public interface ICommand { }

// command and result unrelated

public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand, TResult>
    where TCommand : ICommand
{
    TResult Execute(TCommand command);
}

public interface ICommandValidator<TCommand>
{
    ICollection<ValidationRule> BrokenRules(TCommand command);
}

public class CommandBus : 
    IObserver<CreateItemCommand>, IObservable<CreateItemResult>,  
    IObserver<PokeItemCommand>, IObservable<PokeItemResut>, 
    ....
```

This way, bus needn't be synchronous.